# Error RPN in PHP

Tags: php, math, rpn

I'm trying to use RPN in order to do a simple calculator in PHP.
I tried to follow the wiki description and several tutorial in order to do it but i'm currently meeting a an issue with the first Operand. I can't assign it with the end().

My issue come from the line $nb1 = end($stack);

```
<?php

function add($stack, $nb1, $nb2)
{
    array_push($stack, $nb1 + $nb2);
    $result = $nb1 + $nb2;
    echo $nb1 . ' + ' . $nb2 . ' = ' . $result . "\n";
}

function sub($stack, $nb1, $nb2)
{
    array_push($stack, $nb1 - $nb2);
    $result = $nb1 - $nb2;
    echo $nb1 . ' - ' . $nb2 . ' = ' . $result . "\n";
}

function div($stack, $nb1, $nb2)
{
    array_push($stack, $nb1 / $nb2);
    $result = $nb1 / $nb2;
    echo $nb1 . ' / ' . $nb2 . ' = ' . $result . "\n";
}

function mul($stack, $nb1, $nb2)
{
    array_push($stack, $nb1 * $nb2);
    $result = $nb1 * $nb2;
    echo $nb1 . ' * ' . $nb2 . ' = ' . $result . "\n";
}

function calc($input)
{
$stack = array();
$token = explode(" ", trim($input));
$count = count($token);
// echo $count . "\n";
// print_r($token);

for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $tokenNUm = "";

    if (is_numeric($token[$i])) {
        array_push($stack, $token[$i]);
        print_r($token);
    } else {
        $nb2 = end($stack);
        array_pop($stack);
        $nb1 = end($stack);
        array_pop($stack);
        echo "nb1 : ". $nb1 . "\n";
        echo "nb2 : ". $nb2 . "\n";

        switch($token[$i]) {
        case '+':
            add($stack, $nb1, $nb2);
        case '-':
            sub($stack, $nb1, $nb2);
        case '/':
            div($stack, $nb1, $nb2);
        case '*':
            mul($stack, $nb1, $nb2);
        default:
            die('Error');
        }
    }
    return end($stack);
    }
}

echo "Final result = " . calc($argv[1]) . "\n";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not diving too deep into the logic I can point out on couple mistakes you made:

1. Your `return end($stack);` is inside the `for` loop. Basically, your loop will only run the first iteration and then exits the function.
2. You have to put `break;` in every `case` block, otherwise it will execute every single function in the `switch` block and die with error:

   ```
   switch($token[$i]) {
       case '+':
           add($stack, $nb1, $nb2);
           break;
       case '-':
           sub($stack, $nb1, $nb2);
           break;
       case '/':
           div($stack, $nb1, $nb2);
           break;
       case '*':
           mul($stack, $nb1, $nb2);
           break;
       default:
           die('Error');
   }
   ```

Hope these would help.

**Update**:

Forgot to mention that you have to run you script like that `php rpn.php "1 + 2"` because you are using `$argv[1]`. Assuming `rpn.php` is the name of your file. Here is the [DEMO](https://3v4l.org/HGkSc). Try running it with and without my suggestions, you will see the difference. It doesn't fix your algorithm but it fixes the error you were talking about.

Comment: I tried what you said but it doesn't change anything